# How can i automatically (FTP) upload files when saving with Netbeans?

Tags: ftp, netbeans

I am building a php project with Netbeans. Is there a way to automatically upload the files to the host when saving, using FTP?

Comment: filezilla tag doesn't make sense really here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, upload 'on save' option available in "run configuration" option of Netbeans where you can configure remote FTP setting.